# Is this conclusion from $⟨\alpha⟩=⟨\alpha^k⟩$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $K=⟨\alpha⟩$ to be a cyclic finite group, my tutor stated that there is $f:K \rightarrow K$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha^k$, he said that it's a consequence from the statement bellow:

If $a$ also generates $K$ so there is a automorphism $f$ as $f(\alpha)=a$.

Then I think that $\alpha^k$ generates $K$ as well:

$⟨\alpha⟩=\{(\alpha^k)^n;\ n \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{\alpha^{kn};\ n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

since $kn \in \mathbb{Z}$

Is my point right?

Comment: $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$ but $2$ doesn't.

Comment: we need context. are we in a group? Is it finite? How s it made?

Comment: What is wrong? z

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious to everyone else but what is a monitor?

Comment: tutor...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the order of $\alpha^{k}$ is the least $m$ such that $km=o(\alpha)n$ for some $n$. Therefore, $m$ is of the form $\frac{o(\alpha)}{k/n}$ ($*$), and hence $o(\alpha^{k})$ ("...*the least*...") is gotten when the denominator in ($*$) is *the greatest* divisor of $k$ which is *also* a divisor of $o(\alpha)$: $$o(\alpha^k)=\frac{o(\alpha)}{\gcd(k,o(\alpha))}$$
So, in general, $\langle \alpha ^k\rangle $ is a *proper* subgroup of $\langle \alpha\rangle $, unless $k$ and $o(\alpha)$ are relatively prime.

(For example, think (additively!) of $G:=(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,+)$: $1$ is a generator; which among $2\cdot 1=2$, $3\cdot 1=3$, $4\cdot 1=4$, $5\cdot 1=5$ are also generators of $G$?)

Comment: If both groups have the same size so are they equal to each other?

Comment: Yes, @DaviAmérico, if they have the same order ("size"), then they are equal. And this happens iff $k$ and $o(\alpha)$ are coprime.